# Keep the background interface enabled when a Ionic Modal view is shown/opened

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to customize a modal view for a webapp I'm working on. 
I'm still new to ionic and I've already checked the documentation but I couldn't find how I could keep the background interface enabled.

The modal view is used here to display a small form on the bottom of the screen. Keeping in sight the original UI. What I want to do is to open and close the modal view using the same button, which is located outside of the modal view.

[image]

Thanks for helping me :). If you need more details, feel free to ask.

**Clarifications :**

I already know how to open or close a modal. The thing is, when you open a modal. The modal disable everything else. On the gif you can see that the cursor isn't changing back to the pointer when the modal is opened. What I want to do is to disable this behaviour so I can click back on the very same button to close the modal.